# Docker ENTRYPOINT maximum number of characters

Tags: docker

What is the maximum amount of characters I can put into ENTRYPOINT like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","-c","export NGINX_CONF=<base64stuff>; echo '<base64stuff>' | base64 -d | sh;"]
```

Environment:

- AWS ECS cluster
- Docker (not Docker Swarm)
- everything via Terraform

Comment: Don't think there is a limit. But why not execute a script from using ENTRYPOINT which has all you commands?

Comment: I'm doing that as well but I'm doing string interpolation with Terraform and so I can't put everything into the script file. Background: I'm looking for an alternative for using AWS SSM parameters (4kb limit) to provision files to containers at runtime